# Save one model in another model in Entity Framework 6 code-first

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first

I have two model classes, `Move` and `PlanMove`. Each `PlanMove` object must have a `Move` object, in other words each `PlanMove` has one `Move` and `Move` is an independent class.

I create a `Move` model class like this:

```
 public class Move : BaseModel
 {
        [Display(Name = "نام حرکت")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "توضیح حرکت")]
        [UIHint("_SummerNote")]
        [AllowHtml]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "تصویر")]
        public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "تصویر بندانگشتی")]
        public string ThumbnailImageUrl { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "فیلم")]
        public string VideoUrl { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "گروه حرکت")]
        [ForeignKey("MoveGroup")]
        public string MoveGroupId { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<MoveGroup> MoveGroup { get; set; }
}
```

Note: the `Move` model class is an independent model class.

And I created `PlanMove` like this:

```
public class PlanMove:BaseModel
{
        [ForeignKey("FitnessPlanDay")]
        public Guid FitnessPlanDayId { get; set; }
        [Display(Name="حرکات جایگزین")]
        public List<Move> AlternativeMove { get; set; }
        [Display(Name="دفعات تکرار حرکت")]
        public byte Count { get; set; }
        [Display(Name="دفعات ست حرکت")]
        public byte Set { get; set; }
        [Display(Name="شماره گروه حرکات سوپر")]
        public byte? SuperNumber { get; set; }
        [Display(Name="تعداد ست مجموع حرکات سوپر")]
        public byte? SuperSet { get; set; }
        [Display(Name="میزان فشار وزنه بر بدن")]
        public WeighPressure WeighPressure { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Move")]
        public Guid MoveId { get; set; }
        public virtual Move Move { get; set; }
        public virtual FitnessPlanDay FitnessPlanDay { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see in the above class for save one `Move` model (that is an independent model class), I wrote these properties:

```
    [ForeignKey("Move")]
    public Guid MoveId { get; set; }
    public virtual Move Move { get; set; }
```

but Entity Framework 6 code first creates a `PlanMove_Id` column for `Move` class in the database. I said this model is independent and does not need to communicate with another model (I mean was `PlanMove` model class).

T-SQL `Move` table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Moves] 
(
    [Id] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT (newsequentialid()) NOT NULL,
    [Name] NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL,
    [Description] NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL,
    [ImageUrl] NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL,
    [ThumbnailImageUrl] NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL,
    [VideoUrl] NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL,
    [MoveGroupId] NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL,
    [PlanMove_Id] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Moves] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),

    CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Moves_dbo.PlanMoves_PlanMove_Id] 
         FOREIGN KEY ([PlanMove_Id]) REFERENCES [dbo].[PlanMoves]([Id])
);
```

But `PlanMove` model is ok.

Surely some of my work is wrong,How can I save an independent model to another model?

Comment: you have the property AlternativeMove on PlanMove. should this be part of EF's model? (since that's most likely where this FK comes from)

Comment: @DevilSuichiro `public List<Move> AlternativeMove { get; set; }` it's simple property that save list of move . I  Remove `MoveId` and change `public virtual Move Move { get; set; }` to `public Move OrginalMove { get; set; }` but still create `PlanMove_Id`

Comment: I don't no why Create a relationship between `Move` and `PlanMove` tables

Comment: depending on wether you want the navigation property reflected in your model you should either map it to an appropriate FK column you deem fit (optimally with an inverse navigation property, too) or ignore this navigation property. Your comment didn't really explain anything.

Comment: An independent table to store data requires a relationship between that table and the current table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
For this case, I need to have 2 relationships between the two tables. A relationship is one to many and many to many.

> The InverseProperty attribute is used when two entities have more than
>   one relationship.
>
> you can use the `InverseProperty` and `ForeignKey` attributes to configure
>   multiple relationships between the same entities.

So i change my models to :

move:

```
public class Move : BaseModel
    {
        [Display(Name = "نام حرکت")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "توضیح حرکت")]
        [UIHint("_SummerNote")]
        [AllowHtml]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "تصویر")]
        public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "تصویر بندانگشتی")]
        public string ThumbnailImageUrl { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "فیلم")]
        public string VideoUrl { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "گروه حرکت")]
        [ForeignKey("MoveGroup")]
        public string MoveGroupId { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<MoveGroup> MoveGroup { get; set; }

        [InverseProperty("OrginalMove")]
        public virtual ICollection<PlanMove> Orginal { get; set; }


        [InverseProperty("AlternativePlanMoves")]
        public virtual ICollection<PlanMove> AlternativeMove { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and PlanMove:

```
 public class PlanMove:BaseModel
    {
        [Display(Name="دفعات تکرار حرکت")]
        public byte Count { get; set; }
        [Display(Name="دفعات ست حرکت")]
        public byte Set { get; set; }
        [Display(Name="شماره گروه حرکات سوپر")]
        public byte? SuperNumber { get; set; }
        [Display(Name="تعداد ست مجموع حرکات سوپر")]
        public byte? SuperSet { get; set; }
        [Display(Name="میزان فشار وزنه بر بدن")]
        public WeighPressure WeighPressure { get; set; }


        [Display(Name = "حرکات جایگزین")]
        public virtual ICollection<Move> AlternativePlanMoves { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("OrginalMove")]
        public Guid? MoveId { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "حرکت")]
        public virtual Move OrginalMove { get; set; }


        [ForeignKey("FitnessPlanDay")]
        public Guid FitnessPlanDayId { get; set; }
        public virtual FitnessPlanDay FitnessPlanDay { get; set; }

    }
```

for more info: [MoreInfo](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/inverseproperty-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx)

Comment: In addition to your statement, a relationship can also be one to one